# Delphi-Excel-Pivot - Identifying Row Level

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, com

I am using a Delphi App to build an Excel (2013) spreadsheet.  As part of this spreadsheet, I am building a Pivot Table. The rows in this Pivot table have a multi-level hierarchy.  For example, State -> City.  So for each state, multiple cities are listed, and I can collapse on state.  This is not the exact data that is used, but it is easiest to explain.  Elsewhere in my code, I am looping through all the rows in the Pivot table, reading the value in Column 'A', which would be either a state or a city.  How can I ask the Pivot table if a given row is a top level row (aka State) or a level 2 row (aka City)?  I CANNOT use the data, I have to ask the Pivot table itself, but I can't find any applicable properties.

In Delphi, I have a handle to my Pivot Table, and I can determine top and bottom rows, and loop through that.  I just can't determine how to identify is this a top level row or not...

```
    CODE FRAGMENT:
    // Get a handle to the PivotTable, then get the address of the Pivot Table
       TerritoryPivot := TerritoryAnalysisSheet.PivotTables(1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT) as PivotTable;
       PivotAddress := TerritoryPivot.TableRange1.Address[True, True, xlR1C1, EmptyParam, EmptyParam];
       PivotAddressElements := ParseR1C1Range(PivotAddress);

       // Now build a stringlist containing all the Names in Order.
       for j := PivotAddressElements.FirstRow +2 to PivotAddressElements.LastRow -1 do
begin
if TerritoryAnalysisSheet.Range['A' + IntToStr(J), EmptyParam].IS_THIS_LEVEL_1) == true then
...       
end;
```

What I need is a real property/method, instead of the 'IS_THIS_LEVEL_1' pseudo property.

Comment: You may want to include your code in your question.

Comment: Done...  Added code fragment.

Comment: @user1009073 You don't mention what you're actually using to write to the spreadsheet.

Comment: The program is written in Delphi (Seattle), which makes COM calls to Excel 2013